# how does nodejs link all built-in c/c++ modules

Tags: node.js

Since version 0.11.11, `src/node_extensions.h`, from where all built-in c/c++ modules are linked, has been removed. I wonder from where are these `node_xxx` built-in modules linked now? Is it from `node.gyp`?

Meanwhile, I have checked `get_builtin_module` function in `src/node.cc`. That indicates the built-in modules chaining in `modlist_builtin`. So my question could also be where does this `modlist_builtin` come from.